# Get ChildElement without using element selector

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I am using a protractor to get the text in the second Div within #myDiv. Can someone please advise how can I get a text from the second Div (complete Text) which is 'This is a sample text'. I tried getting text in #myDiv but it adds spaces before the phrase. I want to exactly get the text from the 2nd child element of the after #myDiv.

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    <span> (this is second div)
        <a name="aTag"></a>
        <madcap:concept term="DoSomething">
            This
            <span class="myClass">
                is a 
            </span>
            sample text
        </madcap:concept></h1>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try with following-sibling xpath as below :

```
element(by.xpath("//*[following-sibling::div[@id='myDiv']]"))
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

```
let text = await element(by.xpath('//div[@id="myDiv"]//span[1]')).getText();
console.log(text)
```

worked fine for me

[image]

I added your html in component html and checked it.